# Host IIS sites alongside SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, hosting

I know the premise around SharePoint and IIS, where SharePoint takes on Port 80 as the default, which is fine.

Question is, is there a way to host IIS web sites, along side SharePoint on the same box? We have a POC we're building for a client and need to have SharePoint accessible to them, but we only have one hosting environment, which runs other IIS applications as well?

Answer (score 2):

1st thing, sharepoint is not capturing the port 80( their is no hard requirement for it). When you create the SharePoint Web Application, you can select the port number other than 80 and also provide the host header.

For Non-SharePoint sites, you can simple create another web site in IIS on a port which is not being used.

If you want same host header for sites( SharePoint & Non-SharePoint) then you need different port numbers for both. i.e one is used port 3000 and 2nd can use 3001.

Answer (score 1):

There should no problem doing this. You can even make SharePoint not use port 80 if you want. When you create a new Web Application in SharePoint you provide the host header and port.